# React-Redux: Infinite loop when concat to an array in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, infinite-loop, redux

So I am trying to add elements to an array I have stored in the state. I know you are not supposed to mutate the state directly, so I found that using `concat` is the best way of doing it.

However when I try doing this, I get an infinite loop.

reducer.js:

```
const initialState = {
  name : null, //puzzle name
  start : []
};

export default createReducer(initialState,{
  [START_PROCESS]: (state,payload) => {
    return Object.assign({},state,{
      start : state.start.concat(['test']);
    })
  }
});
```

the result is `['test','test','test','test'...`

e.g:

- setting `start: state.start` works
- setting `start: state.start + 'test'` results in an infinite loop of `testtesttest..`

I don't know what causes this weird behavior. From what I know the state is only modified this way by creating a new state so there is no way it could feed back into itself.

createReducer.js

```
export function createReducer(initialState, reducerMap) {
    return (state = initialState, action) => {
        const reducer = reducerMap[action.type];

        return reducer
            ? reducer(state, action.payload)
            : state;
    };
}
```

startAction.js

```
const START_PROCESS = 'START_PROCESS';
export function startProcess(data) {
  return {
    type : START_PROCESS,
    payload : {
      data : data //where data is a string
    }
  }
}
```

viewAction.js

```
...
export default ProcessView extends React.Component {
  render() { return <div>{this.props.actions.startProcess('string')}</div> }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ProcessView)
```

Comment: syntax looks to be correct. how do you call `START_PROCESS` action?

Comment: question updated with full trace

Comment: how is `startAction` called?

Comment: Its a typo, meant to be `startProcess` That said I think I see the issue. Correct me if im wrong, since `startProcess` is called in the body of render, it is called every time the state  changes, resulting in an infinite loop?

Comment: when you call this action from render method it will update state and re-render view. like render -> call action -> reduce state -> render -> call action -> ... and thats why it is concatenating infinitely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way of avoiding state mutation is definitely with [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/). In your case I would say that maybe you call your action wrong. Are you sure it is not called inside render?

Comment: I'll check that out. Also the action is indeed called inside a render. Do you think that may have caused something?

Comment: Yes if you call it inside render you will enter an infinite loop. Because the action will always call itself as every action causes the page to call render again.